# How to bind javascript object array to a table using knockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js

```
 I have a GetMainTestResuls mothed that returns the following data using pre tab.

    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(GetMainTestResult, null, 2)"></pre>

[
 [],
 [
  {
     "groupTestName": "Test Group 1",
    "groupTestData": [
    {
      "sectionName": "Section 1",
      "testName": "Test Group 1",
      "totalPassExpect": 10,
      "totalPassRate": "100.00",
      "totalDuration": "30:44:25",
      "loopPassExpected": 10,
      "loopPassRate": "10%",
      "loopDuration": "70:44:25"
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "Section 1",
      "testName": " Test Group 1",
      "totalPassExpect": 200,
      "totalPassRate": "99.50",
      "totalDuration": "01:39:53",
      "loopPassExpected": 100,
      "loopPassRate": "99.00",
      "loopDuration": "600:55:28"
    },
    {
      "sectionName": " Section 1",
      "testName": " Test Group 1",
      "totalPassExpect": 300,
      "totalPassRate": "99.67",
      "totalDuration": "02:27:57",
      "loopPassExpected": 100,
      "loopPassRate": "10.00",
      "loopDuration": "400:48:04"
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  "groupTestName": "Test Group 2",
  .....
    and I am trying to bind this data to my table body as the following. 
   <!-- ko foreach: GetMainTestResult -->
                 <!-- ko if:$data.length > 0 -->                
                    <div class="SubHeaderFont col-lg-offset-2 headerTitle">Main Test</div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              ... 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- ko foreach: $data.groupTestData -->
                            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->

                            <tr>
                                <td>Section<span data-bind="text: $data.sectionName"></span></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassExpect"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassRate"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalDuration"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassExpected"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassRate"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopDuration"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.testName"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassExpect"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassRate"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalDuration"></td>
                                <!-- ko if:$index() > 0 -->
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassExpected"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassRate"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopDuration"></td>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </tr>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
     ....
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko-->
```

My viewModel works fine and the table header which is I bind to other object also working but the table body is not displaying any data except the table header. What is wrong here? Can you please help?

Comment: a JS fiddle example would help us to check the issue. Also Let us know if you are getting any exception in your console.

Comment: I din't get any exception. The page runs fine and displays all the other data.

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful I guess

Answer (score 0):

You expect `$data` to be a test group here:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.groupTestData -->
```

but its an array of testgroups, defined by:

```
<!-- ko foreach: GetMainTestResult -->
```

You are missing another loop, as `GetMainTestResult` is an array of arrays of test groups.

### Edit:

You can for example show a table for each test group like this:

**1-** `<!-- ko foreach: GetMainTestResult -->` to loop over test groups
 **2-** `<!-- ko foreach: groupTestData -->`     to loop over test group data

```
<!-- ko foreach: GetMainTestResult -->
    <!-- ko if:$data.length > 0 -->
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->              <!-- *** the new loop *** -->
    <div class="SubHeaderFont col-lg-offset-2 headerTitle"
         data-bind="text: groupTestName">
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              ... 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: groupTestData -->
            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <tr>
                <td>Section<span data-bind="text: $data.sectionName"></span></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassExpect"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassRate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalDuration"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassExpected"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassRate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopDuration"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.testName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassExpect"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalPassRate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.totalDuration"></td>
                <!-- ko if:$index() > 0 -->
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassExpected"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopPassRate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.loopDuration"></td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko-->
<!-- /ko-->
```

Comment: So how do you get into the GroupTestData? Can I do it like this foreach: $data.$data.groupTestData? Can you give me an example how to go through foreach groupTestData array?

Comment: answer updated with a possible display configuration.